# I have set index then, when i take back up does not display index details

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb, myisam, database-backups

I set index for mysql table, when i take backup using query browser , mysqlworkbench dose not display index details. What is the problem or else any mine mistake.

See mine table. I have set index for "id" column but not display that details.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testsakthi` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

My Question is where is index details? EX:

```
CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT, parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

I have found some url they told some idea. see title " NO_KEY_OPTIONS "

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html

Comment: Works for me. What steps are you taking? Please be specific.

Comment: See my table CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testsakthi` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqldump` from the command-line if possible, and the indexes will be dumped too:

```sh
mysqldump -R --user=username --password=password dnname > outputfile.sql
```

Comment: This comment is not working. please let me how to get dumb in my local machine "WAMP SERVER"

Comment: You have to locate the `mysqldump` executable inside your wamp folder, and run it from there, via DOS prompt. But your question is not very clear. The code you posted does include index information (`PRIMARY KEY`, `KEY`...).